# Проблемы с реализацией итератора

Tags: python

Задание:

> 1. Написать итератор, который принимает список списков, и возвращает их плоское представление, т.е последовательность состоящую из вложенных элементов. Например
>
> ```
> nested_list = [
>   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
>   ['d', 'e', 'f', 'h', False],
>   [1, 2, None],
> ]
> for item in FlatIterator(nested_list):
>   print(item) #
> ```
>
> Должен отпечататься каждый элемент каждого вложенного списка
>
> ```
> 'a' 
> 'b' 
> 'c' 
> 'd'
> 'e'
> 'f'
> 'h'
> False
> 1
> 2
> None
> ```
>
> а комперхеншн, выражение вернет плоский список `flat_list = [item for item in FlatIterator(nested_list)]`
>
> во `flat_list` должен быть такой список: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', False, 1, 2, None]`

https://github.com/netology-code/py-homeworks-advanced/tree/master/2.Iterators.Generators.Yield  - Задача №1

Мое решение:

```
nested_list = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f','h',False],
    [1, 2, None],
]
class Nested_iter:
    def __init__(self,nested_list):
        self.start = -1
        self.end = len(nested_list)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.main_list_cursor = 0
        self.nested_list_cursor = 0

    def __next__(self):
        self.start += 1
        if self.start == self.end:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.main_list[self.main_list_cursor][self.nested_list_cursor]

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(elem) for elem in nested_list[self.start])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in Nested_iter(nested_list):
        print(item)
```

Comment: у вас задание связано с использованием `yield`, а вы класс написали.

Comment: Добрый день Yield идет в задание под номером 2! Мне надо Первую часть)

Comment: попробовал ваш код и словил ошибку TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'  вы хотябы предупредили что код не рабочий..

Comment: Не думаю, что хорошей идеей было клеить строку (это где _str_), заворачивают скорее всего из-за этого...

Comment: Ошибка из-за того, что `__iter__` должна **обязательно** возвращать итерируемый объект, это указано в документации

Comment: `__str__` обращается к глобальной переменной `nested_list`. По условию задания `__str__` вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 5):

Ваш код можно значительно упростить следующим образом:

1. Избавляемся в `__init__` от `self.start` и `self.end` (первое — потому что не нужно из-за указателей, второе можно заменить на `self.list_len`) и добавляем `self.lst`, куда будем класть список. Кстати, `self.cursor` — переменную для прохода по основному списку — можно определить прямо там же.
2. Исходя из п. 1, при каждой итерации мы увеличиваем основной курсор на 1 и одновременно создаём вложенный курсор `self.nest_cursor`. И да, нужно обязательно возвращать итерируемый объект через `self`.
3. В `__next__` у нас есть две проверки: проверка на то, что курсор вложенного списка дошёл до конца (тогда мы вызываем `iter` и переходим к следующему подсписку), и проверка на то, что курсор основного списка дошёл до конца (останавливаем итератор). После этого мы увеличиваем курсор вложенный на 1 и в конце возвращаем текущий элемент списка (не забываем про вложенный курсор).

Далее третий пункт повторяется до прохождения второй проверки и завершения работы. Я ещё позволил себе переписать названия некоторых полей класса, т.к. выглядело это как небольшой перегруз.

```py
nested_list = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f','h',False],
    [1, 2, None],
]

class FlatIterator:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.cursor = -1
        self.list_len = len(self.lst)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.cursor += 1
        self.nest_cursor = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.nest_cursor == len(self.lst[self.cursor]):
          iter(self)
        if self.cursor == self.list_len:
          raise StopIteration
        self.nest_cursor += 1     
        return self.lst[self.cursor][self.nest_cursor - 1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  flat_list = [item for item in FlatIterator(nested_list)]
  print(flat_list)

# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', False, 1, 2, None]
```

Надеюсь, мой ответ был полезен.

UPD: вижу ещё замечания от @Stanislav Volodarskiy, попробую на них ответить:

- `Не работает next(FlatIterator(nested_list))` — это оттого, что не было в инициализации `self.nest_cursor`.
- `Вызов iter на вашем объекте меняет его состояние. Этого не должно быть.` — в данном случае это *необходимо*, поскольку надо же как-то переходить к следующим элементам/спискам при определённых условиях, верно? Впрочем, если будут альтернативные решения, то буду рад их вылсушать.
- `Итератор сломается если среди вложенных списков будет пустой. :(`  — действительно :( В коде тогда стоит добавить `while`, который будет одновременно следить за невыходом из основного списка и текущего подсписка.

Учитывая всё вышесказанное, прилагаю исправленный код:

```py
nested_list = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f','h',False],
    [1, 2, None],
]

class FlatIterator:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.cursor = -1
        self.nest_cursor = 0
        self.list_len = len(self.lst)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.cursor += 1
        self.nest_cursor = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while self.cursor - self.list_len and self.nest_cursor == len(self.lst[self.cursor]):
          iter(self)
        if self.cursor == self.list_len:
          raise StopIteration
        self.nest_cursor += 1     
        return self.lst[self.cursor][self.nest_cursor - 1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  flat_list = [item for item in FlatIterator(nested_list)]
  print(flat_list)
```

Comment: имена `list` и `len` зарезервированы в `python`.

Comment: @n1tr0xs спасибо за замечания, переписал на нерезервные

Comment: Вызов `iter` на вашем объекте меняет его состояние. Этого не должно быть.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавил ответы к Вашим замечаниям и переделал код в соответствии с ними

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно сложно написать итератор соблюдая все правила:

Метод `__iter__` всегда должен возвращать итератор. *У вас не так.*

Метод `__iter__` не должен менять состояние исходного объекта (если вам всё-таки нужно меняющееся  состояние, вы должны создать и вернуть другой объект). *У вас не так.*

Если метод `__next__` однажды выбросил `StopIteration`, он должен делать это и далее. *У вас не так.*

Во время итерации не надо заглядывать дальше чем это минимально необходимо.

Надо правильно обрабатывать пустые подсписки. *У вас будет ошибка.*

Желательно аккуратно работать на меняющихся списках. Это касается и списка верхнего уровня и его подсписков. Пользователь может добавлять, удалять элементы и целые списки во время работы итерации. *Вы сохраняете длину списка.*

Код ниже соответствует всем требованиям.

```
class NestedIterator:
    def __init__(self, list_):
        self._stopped = False
        self._list = list_
        self._i = 0
        self._j = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self._stopped:
            while self._i < len(self._list):
                if self._j < len(self._list[self._i]):
                    v = self._list[self._i][self._j]
                    self._j += 1
                    return v

                self._i += 1
                self._j = 0
            self._stopped = True
        raise StopIteration


def main():
    nested_list = [
        ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
        [],
        [],
        ['i', 'j', 'k'],
        []
    ]

    print(next(NestedIterator(nested_list)))
    flat_list = list(NestedIterator(nested_list))
    print(*flat_list)


main()
```